# i have 2 inputs one is a sentence the second is the search string in c++

Tags: c++

I need to find the search string in the sentence and if the search string ends with a '.' it will search for the word and check if it starts with the string, but my program is calling an abort i cant tell why.

Search String ends with a ‘+’: The word must start with the search string.
Example:
Enter source string: Cars are fast END
Enter search string: fa+
index: 9 word: fast

```
        int main() 
{
        string words, search, error;
        int x;
    

        cout << "Enter source string: ";
        cin >> words;
        source_string( words);
    
        cout << "Enter search string: ";
        cin >> search;
    
    
        while ( !(search == "quit" || search == "QUIT") )
        {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length(); i++)
        {
            if (  !(search.at(-1) == '.' || search.at(-1) == '+' || search.at(-1) == '*') )
            {
                cout << "Enter search string: ";
                cin >> search;
            }

            else
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin >> error;
                if ( search.at(-1) == '+')
                {
                    x = words.find(search);
                    if ( words.at(x-1) == ' ')
                        cout << "index: " << x << " word: " << words.at(x);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: what do you expect `search.at(-1)` to do?

Comment: `search.at(-1)` is never valid in C++.

Comment: Never knew that thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Negative indices are not allowed in C++.

Languages which allow a negative indices in an array are just creating syntactic sugar for

`(the length of the string + user_entered_index)`

e.g.
`my_str.at(my_str.length() - 1)`